# Application hangs on peak load using spring and c3p0

Tags: spring, connection-pooling, c3p0

I am using these connection setting for spring application with c3p0.
On peak load the application hangs. On peak load number of user upload xml files and application unmarshall and save in database, files are quite large normally it takes 20 to 30s to complete. Application start taking more time (after 2 min of load starts) to complete the process from 40s to 200s and stop responding after 3 mins on peak load.

## Connection pool Settings

```
INITIAL_POOL_SIZE=25 NUM_HELPER_THREAD=6 ACQUIRE_INCREMENT=5 MAX_IDLE_TIME_EXCESS_CONNECTIONS=0 PREFERRED_TEST_QUERY=SELECT 1 FROM DUAL IS_TEST_CONNECTIONON_CHECKIN=TRUE IS_TEST_CONNECTIONON_CHECKOUT=FALSE IS_DEBUG_UNRETURNED_CONNECTION_STACK_TRACES=TRUE IDLE_CONNECTION_TEST_PERIOD=300 #MaxPoolSize 
MAX_CONNECTIONS=150 MIN_POOL_SIZE=25 MAX_STATEMENTS_PER_CONNECTION=100 MAX_STATEMENTS=1000
IDLE_CONNECTION_TEST_PERIOD=300 MAX_CONNECTION_AGE=1944000
```

Please suggest!!

C3p0 initialize with acquireIncrement -> 5, acquireRetryAttempts -> 30, acquireRetryDelay -> 500, autoCommitOnClose -> false, automaticTestTable -> null, breakAfterAcquireFailure -> false, checkoutTimeout -> 0, connectionCustomizerClassName -> null, connectionTesterClassName -> com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.DefaultConnectionTester, dataSourceName -> 2upg5n90m6dhnua9spyw|6ae354b6, debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces -> true, description -> null, driverClass -> oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver, factoryClassLocation -> null, forceIgnoreUnresolvedTransactions -> false,  idleConnectionTestPeriod -> 300, initialPoolSize -> 25, jdbcUrl -> XXX, maxAdministrativeTaskTime -> 0, maxConnectionAge -> 1944000, maxIdleTime -> 0, maxIdleTimeExcessConnections -> 0, maxPoolSize -> 150, maxStatements -> 1000, maxStatementsPerConnection -> 100, minPoolSize -> 25, numHelperThreads -> 6, numThreadsAwaitingCheckoutDefaultUser -> 0,  preferredTestQuery -> SELECT 1 FROM DUAL, propertyCycle -> 0, testConnectionOnCheckin -> true, testConnectionOnCheckout -> false, unreturnedConnectionTimeout -> 0, usesTraditionalReflectiveProxies -> false ]

Configuration :

```
  <bean id="dataSourceFactory" class="com.common.CLDataSourceFactory"/>
    <bean id="dataSource" factory-bean="dataSourceFactory" factory-method="createInstance"/>
```

Code from CLDataSourceFactory

```
private static final CLDataSource INSTANCE = new CLDataSource();        
private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(CLDataSourceFactory.class);
/** This is the JVM shutdown hook to close the data source. */
static {
    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                LOGGER.info("JVM shutdown hook [CLSourceFactory's close data source] has been initiated.");
                INSTANCE.close();
                LOGGER.info("CLDataSourceFactory's close data source has been completed.");
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                LOGGER.error("Exception occured while CLDataSourceFactory's close data source: " + ex, ex);
            }
        }
    });
}   

public CLDataSource createInstance() {
    return INSTANCE; 
}
```

Comment: Could this be a OOM problem?

Comment: I would say no or not properly setup of transactions leading to pool starvation. Please post your spring configuration and web.xml.

Comment: these names are similar to, but not actually, c3p0 property names. how are you configuring your pool? it'd be a good idea to verify that you are actually setting the config you mean to set. c3p0 dumps its config at INFO on pool initialization.

Comment: @SteveWaldman Added C3p0 inilialization info